# How to implement live search / search view on large SQL Database

Tags: java, android

Am here not asking for someone to write out an example, am looking for more input on ways to accomplish this, and why. (Guidance as such)

I have been trying and reading about Listview, But from what i understand, Listview and using search with it, would only work with a relatively small data set. (I am having a hard time getting to grips with it)

I am wanting to search a table (Across the network currently using jdbc:jtds) and the table can contain anything from 1,000 - 500,000 lines.
(An i know people are going to advise against it, but its more for internal application usage than public release)

The way i understand SearchView is its Android Implementation of the Ajax live search, and if so then it would need an array of data to filter through. 
To pre load 500,000 would be impracticable, Am i correct in thinking this?

The method i was thinking was creating a new activity with multiple Textfields, and a query behind each one or multiples and performing a search based on the text that has been inputted and the user pressing a Submit / Search.

The draw back of this, is its more old school with back and forth process if a typo has been made, Where the SearchView would be interactive display results straight away from what the user starts to type in.

Could someone advise what may be the best method to do this? There appears to be way too many ways to search for data in java / android and am getting lost in the number of ways to do this.

(There is no Database being held locally, this is all purely running of a local network only. 
I have currently been trying with Listadapter and SearchBinding)

Comment: Hi Dave maybe you can check following link https://camposha.info/android-sqlite-crud-recyclerview-serverside-search-filter/